# awk to add header to output file

Tags: awk

I am trying to filter a `file_to_filter` by using another `filter_file`, which is just a list of strings in `$1`.  I think I am close but can not seem to include the header row in the output.  The `file_to_filter` is tab delimited as well.  Thank you :).

**file_to_filter**

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    Gene.refGene
chr1    160098543   160098543   G   A   exonic  ATP1A2
chr1    172410967   172410967   G   A   exonic  PIGC
```

**filter_file**

```
PIGC
```

**desired output (header included)**

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    Gene.refGene
chr1    172410967   172410967   G   A   exonic  PIGC
```

**awk with current output (header not included)**

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1{A[$1];next}$7 in A' file test

chr1    172410967   172410967   G   A   exonic  PIGC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your fields really are tab-separated:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{tgts[$1]; next} (FNR==1) || ($7 in tgts)' filter_file file_to_filter
```

To start learning awk, read the book Effective Awk Programing, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.